# Display server response in vuejs template

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am using vuejs and backend Django. When i send request to server then it send response i had use console to display any error in console log. The problem is that i want that response to display in vuejs template. so i don`t have any idea.. so what can i do??

```
login: function () {
    // for storing token sent by server
    axiosInstance({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/auth/jwt/create/',
      data: {
        'password': this.credentials.password,
        'email': this.credentials.email
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.non_field_errors.push(response.data.non_field_errors)
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.data.token)
        this.$cookie.set('accesstoken', response.data.token, 1)
        this.$cookie.set('usertype', response.data.usertype, 1)
        console.log(this.$cookie.get('usertype'))
        this.$router.push('/')
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
        console.error(e)
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a property in data object.

```
data: function() {
  errors: null
}
```

You can set the value of it like this.

```
login: function () {
 let that = this
// for storing token sent by server
axiosInstance({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/auth/jwt/create/',
  data: {
    'password': this.credentials.password,
    'email': this.credentials.email
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    //if success
  })
  .catch(e => {
    //if catch an error
    // set e or any of its props
    that.errors = e
  })
}
```

To display:

```
<pre v-text="errors"></pre>
```

**Updated**

working fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/Zugor/601tdxoe/